# Can I remove other people from my PlayStation Plus subscription?

Tags: ps4, playstation-plus

For various reasons, I want to prevent my cousin from having the benefits of my PlayStation Plus subscription on my PlayStation. Is there a way I can do this?

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look into setting a [passcode](http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/46250/ps4-how-to-set-up-a-local-passcode-for-a-user-profile/) on your account. This is not a fool proof solution, but it appears to be the only one, as you cannot force the PS4 to ask for your PSN credentials when you boot up/log in.

1. Go to Settings -> Login Settings -> Passcode Management
2. Choose a passcode from the on screen prompts.
3. You can also delete the passcode from here, but you will need the passcode that you set.

You will also need to stop the PS4 from auto-logging in to your account, as it will simply boot to a screen asking for your account's passcode. In this case, you will need to create a new account for your cousin to use. This should be effective in stopping your cousin from using your account.

Answer (score 0):

Copied from a now deleted comment by [Schism](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/31508/schism?tab=profile):

> I don't own a PS4, but it seems like you may be able to just deactivate your PS4 as your Primary device. AFAIK, that should let you still use multiplayer, but not any other users. Try deactivating it ([instructions in this link](http://manuals.playstation.net/document/en/ps4/settings/activation.html)) and see if that helps.

Instructions from the link:

> Select  (Settings) > [Account Management] > [Activate as Your Primary PS4] > [Deactivate] on an activated PS4™ system.